# Synchronizing Installed Printers Across Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, printing

We have two Windows 2016 servers. A primary and secondary on the same network. We want to keeps the installed printer for the primary in sync(names, divers, configs) with the secondary. Right now it's a manual process we are trying to automate. Does anyone have some suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 3):

Not true "synchronization", but more like replication:

1. Open Print Management by pressing Windows key + R, then type printmanagement.msc and hit the enter key.
2. Click on Print Management, then select Action from the menu, then Migrate Printers…
3. Choose the option Export printer queues and printer drivers to a file, then simply follow the prompts.
4. Take that resulting file and copy it to your new print server.
5. Open Print Management on the new print server then navigate to Migrate Printers… like before.
6. This time choose Import printer queues and printer drivers to a file and choose the file that you exported from the old print server.
7. Test out printing from your new print server.

Another option is to run print server inside a 2-node cluster - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj556311(v%3Dws.11)